# Fetch dynamic data in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Firstly, I am new in nuxt. What I am trying to do is for every refresh I want to fetch data by calling api and set data to `vuex` store.

If I call it from `mounted` hook then all my problems will be solved but I want to take advantages of `SSR` in nuxt. What I want is to fetch data on server side and use it on client side.

There are two solutions for that- fetch (depricated) and anonymous middleware. It works fine when it is for server side application. My mode is `Universal` and target is `static`, for this configuration, what it does is, during `npm run generate` it calls the api and save the data for one time and use it for my static site.

Main problem is when my data changes, it does not reflect. How to solve this problem efficiently in nuxt by taking the advantage of `SSR` for load data on every page refresh.

And another problem to address, when I refresh my page other than '/', it shows the view of `index.vue`. How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why would you fetch data on server-side if the data can change?? If you control the data change, then build your solution again, otherwise just fetch the data on client-side

Comment: think like, call an action in vuex, every time you refresh page. for page routing it is calling that action only except for index page refresh.